# Ошибка Android Studio - Connection to the Internet denied как исправить

Tags: android, android-studio

Установил Android Studio создал проект и попробовал его собрать, но ничего не получилось, вывело ошибку:

```
Connection to the Internet denied.
```

дальше там есть [ссылка](https://developer.android.com/studio/troubleshoot.html#project_sync_issues) на сайт Android Developers попробовал сделать так как там написано, но тоже не получилось. Насколько я понял Брэндмауер виндовс блокирует это подключение. Как можно исправить эту ошибку чтобы подключиться для синхронизации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему таким способом:

1. Закрыл Android Studio.
2. Перешел в папку пользователя в проводнике Windows (может у кого-то будет другая папка)
3. Удалил папку .gradle
4. Запустил Android Studio и дал ей возможность загрузить все зависимости снова.

Все работает теперь нормально.